# XHR request returns 0 in Safari, 500 in Firefox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, xmlhttprequest

I've run into this funny issue I don't even know how to begin explaining but I'll do my best. So I have a website with a bunch of dynamic pages such as music, movies, etc., each in the form of an `index.php` inside a directory of its name. So, the music page calls the `index.php` in the `/music` folder and so on. I also have a WP blog that sits inside `/blog`.

When you open the music page, it queries a table and lists out the first 12 entries it retrieves. Along with the list, it also adds a "Load More" button to the page. Clicking this button triggers an XHR call to a back-end file (`/assets/engines/more_music_engine.php`). This engine file in turn queries the table for the next 12 entries and echoes the result to the `/music/index.php` page that initially called the engine.

This set up works perfectly fine. Until you visit any of the blog pages (it could be the main blog page or any of its sub-pages, e.g., posts, tags, authors, etc.). When you try revisiting the music page after having visited a blog page first, the XHR breaks down! Not only this, even the status code is not consistent across browsers. On Safari, I get a 0 whereas on Firefox, it's 500. This problem persists until you reload the page in a new tab or window.

Has anyone faced anything similar here and if so, what were the findings? I can share the codes but I need to know which parts to share. The entire dump would be impractically big for pasting here. For starters, here's the JS function making the XHR call:

```
function moretracks(){
    var trackdivs = document.getElementsByTagName('trackitem');
    var countoftracks = trackdivs.length;
    var mus = $('#mus');
    var totalcount = parseInt($('totalcount').text(), 10);
    $('#loadmore-container').remove();
    var waittext = '<div class="loading text-center"><i class="fa fa-4x fa-spinner fa-spin"></i></div>';
    var hr = createXMLHTTPRequestObject();
    var url = 'assets/engines/more_music_engine.php';
    var vars = "count=" + countoftracks + "&totalcount=" + totalcount;
    hr.open("POST", url, true);
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    hr.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200){
            $('.loading').remove();
            var return_data = hr.responseText;
            mus.append(return_data);
        }
        else if(hr.status == 500){
            mus.html("Something went wrong! Please try again later...");
        }
    }
    hr.send(vars);
    mus.append(waittext);
}
```

And here's the button that triggers this function:

```
<button id="loadmore" class="btn btn-lg btn-brown" onClick="moretracks();">See more</button>
```

The page in question is live at peppyburro.com/music.

Here's a portion of the server-side more_music_engine.php file:

```
<?php
require_once 'Admin/Connector.php';
include_once('simplehtmldom_1_5/simple_html_dom.php');

$clientcount = $_POST['count'];
$totalcount = $_POST['totalcount'];
// further processing...
?>
```

I repeat, the response code is 500 in FF and 0 in Safari. Upon debugging and tracing, I found that the server-side script isn't receiving an empty _POST which is hard to explain since the same script works like a charm when the page is reloaded in a different tab.

Here's a dump of my error.log file:

```
[20-Jul-2016 06:40:35 Etc/GMT] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: count in /home/peppyoil/public_html/assets/engines/more_music_engine.php on line 5
[20-Jul-2016 06:40:35 Etc/GMT] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: totalcount in /home/peppyoil/public_html/assets/engines/more_music_engine.php on line 6
[20-Jul-2016 06:40:35 Etc/GMT] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' 12' at line 1' in /home/peppyoil/public_html/assets/engines/more_music_engine.php:12
Stack trace:
#0 /home/peppyoil/public_html/assets/engines/more_music_engine.php(12): PDOStatement->execute()
#1 {main}
  thrown in /home/peppyoil/public_html/assets/engines/more_music_engine.php on line 12
```

Note that this log is only generated when running on FF (500). When running on Safari (response code 0), no log is generated.

**Update**: I replaced XHR with AJAX and the issue persisted. On Firefox, the error thrown is this:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://www.peppyburro.com/assets/engines/more_music_engine.php. (Reason: missing token 'x-requested-with' in CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' from CORS preflight channel).
```

This doesn't make sense since the requesting script is a part of the file (peppyburro.com/music.php) that is also sitting on the same domain!

Comment: If your server returns 500 code, there was a server error. First place to look is in the PHP error logs.

Comment: I did and it shows that the POST was received without any payload which is strange because the same scripts work perfectly fine when the page is reloaded in a new tab. I have updated the question with the server-side code for your review.

Comment: Post received without payload won't caused a 500 server error by itself. What do the error logs actually say? They should point you to a specific line that triggered the error.

Comment: I get that but you're ignoring the other half: 0 on Safari?

Comment: Safari is the new IE - more trouble than it's worth to support /rant

Comment: I'm not ignoring it; either way something is wrong, whether the response code is 0 or 500. If there is a problem, look for errors in the logs first.

Comment: Updated question with more clarity on error logs. Again, like I said, this problem only shows up if you visit the blog page (peppyburro.com/blog or any of its sub-pages) before visiting the music page.

Comment: @TheLearner: I have undone you latest edit, where you added a workaround, but also added a new question, to your post. Either post your workaround as an answer, then ask a *new* question, or re-write your question to ask your new question. "Storyline edits" (such as the one you added) are confusing for future readers.